# React Native app crashes on launch in iOS simulator with assertion failed: 18G95 16G73

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

When running my React Native app (0.61.2) through the terminal or Xcode, it will crash on launch after bundle has fully loaded.
The only clue is from `react-native log-ios` to get a glimpse of why it's crashing.

```
 <Error>: assertion failed: 18G95 16G73: libxpc.dylib + 80528 [5846A329-63C0-3B4F-BC91-F30AF4CA6E30]: 0x7d
Unknown[5116] <Error>:
```

The most Xcode gives me before the crash of the app on launch is:

```
2019-10-29 17:33:41.028898+0800 my_app[6277:117010] [AppCenterCrashes] WARNING: -[MSCrashes configureCrashReporterWithUncaughtExceptionHandlerEnabled:]/656 Detecting crashes is NOT enabled due to running the app with a debugger attached.
2019-10-29 17:33:41.035744+0800 my_app[6277:117010] [AppCenter] WARNING: -[MSAuthTokenContext authTokenHistory]/210 Failed to retrieve history state or none was found.
2019-10-29 17:33:41.035901+0800 my_app[6277:117010] [AppCenter] WARNING: -[MSAuthTokenContext setAuthTokenHistory:]/225 Failed to save new history state.
```

In the terminal, it is simply being started with `react-native run-ios`. This is an ejected app.

This works in the Android emulator, but it crashes on iOS.
To be clear, creating a build for deployment works as well with this exact codebase (we utilize App Center for building and deployment). Only difference is the node version is 8 on App Center whereas locally it's 12.

## What I've tried so far is:

1. Removing node_modules and pods folder completely
2. Clearing haste cache with `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-package-*`
3. Reset metro bundler cache `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*`

## System setup is as follows:

```
System:
    OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8279U CPU @ 2.40GHz
    Memory: 40.67 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
    Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

To note, another React Native project albeit at version 0.60 has no issues running in the same simulator in Xcode.

## Expected output

The app should run without crashing in the iOS simulator when running the command `react-native run-ios`. At the very least the crash should have an identifiable stacktrace but right now I can't even obtain that.

Are there any other steps I can try to further identify where the issue originates from?

If there is a way to to enable Debug JS Remotely before even starting the app to maybe capture a glimpse of the issue in the debugger would also be a great help but this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Unlikely that you're having the same issue, but this just happened to me after installing firebase but I had forgotten to add the GoogleService-Info.plist file, hopefully it helps